# how to rewrite the following for loop in swift 3 syntax?

Tags: swift, for-loop

```
for (int i = n-2; i >= 0; --i)
{
....
}
```

the automatic translation of the above to swift 3 syntax is this

```
for i in n-2 ... 0 
{
}
```

this doesn't work, because n could be 1, in the c syntax, this is valid, the loop won't be triggered,

but in the swift 3 syntax, this will cause runtime error.

Comment: it doesn't cause a runtime error, but it is definitively not equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in stride(from: n-2, through: 0, by: -1) {

}
```

Comment: This never results in `i` being `0`. The to value should be `-1` to have the same functionality as the original post.

Comment: @nathan. Corrected `to:` to `through:`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in (0 ... n-2).reversed() {

}
```